# Convert Bitmap to Mat, FAIL

Tags: bitmap, converters, mat

Sorry a question please, im desesperate haha when execute this code, i dont can convert this image bitmap to mat for create an application with autocrop documents. Here my code:

```
    else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //get the cropped bitmap
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

        //First convert Bitmap to Mat.

        Bitmap myBitmap32 = thePic.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Mat ImageMat = new Mat ( thePic.getHeight(), thePic.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));

        Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, ImageMat);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(ImageMat, ImageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,4);

        findLargestRectangle(ImageMat);
```

When i receive the image crop manually in a bitmap, i want convert this variable to Mat, for after going to an another function for find a largest Rectangle to after autocrop this. But when i write this code, error appears in this line:

Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32, ImageMat);

in "bitmapToMat" and say "from the type utils refers to the missing type bitmap" i dont know if i get bitmap to before.

Please help!, sorry and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code , it's working for me:

```
            Mat img = new Mat();
            String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
            + "/myimg.png";

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img);

            if (img.channels() == 3) {
                Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            } else if (img.channels() == 4) {
                Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
            }
```

photoPath is path to your image, I used Android storage there.
In img is your image from storage.